# Would we include the main engine shield if we were designing the Cassini orbiter today?

Tags: engines, spacecraft-development, saturn, cassini, meteoroid

The Cassini spacecraft flew two bipropellant main engines for major trajectory changes, each with a nominal thrust of 445N (100 lb for us Americans). The engines were located at the aft end of the spacecraft and canted slightly to aim the thrust vectors towards the spacecraft center of mass. So far, this is all conventional design, although having two main engines is unusual and was probably for redundancy given the long mission. However, the design also included a cover for the two engines which could be (and was) opened and closed many times during flight. As far as I know, this feature is unique. Further, it strikes me as a complication which could well have failed (after all, it's a mechanism, and they tend to be much less reliable than most other spacecraft components. According to the link, the cover was implemented to protect a coating on the engines from getting nicked by micrometeorites. I think, but I'm not sure, that this specific coating was also unique to Cassini (at least all the 445N engines I've ever seen are black, not white).

Now my question: Would we do this again? Are we smarter about the micrometeorite flux? Are we flying any engines that are susceptible to minor dings?

As an aside, I can't remember any recent planetary mission proposals with any kind of special protection for main engines. Although maybe I missed it.

Diagram of the Cassini main engine cover.

https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.31.5778&rep=rep1&type=pdf